# Is narrowing of overriden method arguments types a Liskov Substitution Principle violation?

Tags: liskov-substitution-principle

I have this code:

```
abstract class Entity
{
// blah-blah-blah
}

abstract class BaseCollection
{
    public void add(Entity entity);
}
```

And I derive from the Entity and BaseCollection classes:

```
class User extends Entity
{
}

class UserCollection extends BaseCollection
{
   public void add(User user) { // blah-blah-blah }
}
```

Is this an example of Liskov Substitution Principle violation? If it is, how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `User` is a subtype of `Entity` it is perfectly reasonable to add such objects to `BaseCollection` (via `UserCollection`) -- each user is an `Entity`

Passing `UserCollection` where `BaseCollection` is expected, will not work on the other hand: you are expecrted to be able to add an `Entity`, but you need a `User` -- or in other words: when you get an element out of the `UserCollection`, you might get an `Entity` after this, where you expect a `User`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

In my experience, there is often a situation when you need to make the types of arguments of overriden method narrower. But this violates LSP.

So how can I struggle with this issue?

Comment: If you find yourself violating LSP, that means you don't really have an is-a relationship, so inheritance is not the right choice.  Consider composition, some sort of template/generics solution or just simply two non-related classes instead

Comment: OK, but sometimes you need to model some real life situations.  
  
For example, there is class `Human` which has method `call(Doctor doctor)`. And class `Child` extends `Human`. But `Child` cannot accept any doctor. He needs only `Pediatrician` which extends `Doctor`. So `Child` overrides method this way: `call(Pediatrician doctor)`.  
`Child` obviously has "is a" relationship with `Human`. However, this class model violates LSP. How to overcome violation?

Comment: It depends on what pre/post restrictions are associated with call().  If after calling Human.call() the entity must be healed from any disease associated with the doctor's specialty and Child.call() can only be called with a Pediatrician, then (by definition), Child is-not-a Human (maybe rename Human to Adult to better match the class relationship with real-life experience).  If there are no restrictions on Human.call(), you can code Child.call() to only accept Pediatricians by some sort of dynamic casting (and do nothing, throw exception, log error, etc. when called with another doctor)

Comment: So is it acceptable to declare Child.call with Doctor argument (not a Pediatrician) and throw exception after runtime type checking? I thought it is against OOP principles.

Comment: It is not a pure solution, but a pragmatic one: if you _need_ to inherit _and also_ narrow the (effective) type, it is a possibility.  Of course, you need to ensure that all callers of `call()` will only actually supply a `Pediatritian` -- basically the callers need to know that you are passing a `Child`, not a `Human`, at which point the question arises why are you passing the object as a Human, not a Child?

Answer (score 0):

It is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle as other implementations of Entity could not be added to UserCollection.  A user with a reference to a BaseCollection will not expect implemenations that are UserCollections to explode if they provide an Entity other than a User.

I'm assuming that UserCollection.add is replacing BaseCollection.add as you explicitly mentioned narrowing and didn't specify a language.

Method parameters should be contravariant, not covariant if you are following the Liskov Substitution Principle.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.

Comment: "other implementations of User could not be added"  LSP requres that a property on Base should hold on Derived: what is true of an `Entity` is true of `User`.  However, properties of another implementation of a user are not required to hold on `User`

Comment: "User" should have been "Entity" in that sentence.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

If the contract for `BaseCollection` specifies that its `add` method may legitimately be passed any object derived from `Entity`, then the inherited `add` method of `UserCollection` should do likewise, and failure to do so would be a violation of the LSP.  Having `UserCollection` contain an *overload* (not override) of `add` which only accepts objects of type `User` would not violate the LSP if the original `add` method could be used with arbitrary objects derived from `Entity`, though overloading would likely not be particularly appropriate.

If, instead of `add`, the method in question had been something like `setItem(int index, Entity value)` in the base and `setItem(int index, User value)` in the derived class, and if the contract specified that *it was only guaranteed to work with objects which had been read out of the same collection*, then provided that reading the `UserCollection` would never yield anything other than an instance of `User`, the `setItem` method could legitimately reject all objects that weren't instances of `User` without violating the LSP.  If the `setItem` method is going to reject everything that isn't an instance of `user`, then having an overload which accepts only `user` may be useful and appropriate; even though the inherited `setItem` method would need to verify that `value` identified an instance of `User`, an overload which accepted an argument of that type would not.  The biggest caveat when adding such an overload is one should avoid having two unsealed virtual methods that do the same thing; if one is going to add an overload, one should probably override and seal the base-class method so that it converts a passed-in argument to type `User` and then chains to the overloaded version of the method.

Note that arrays subscribe to the latter form of contract and inheritance; a variable of type `Animal[]` may hold a reference to a `Cat[]`; an attempt to store an arbitrary `Animal` into an `Animal[]` which identifies a `Cat[]` could fail, but any `Animal` read out of an `Animal[]` is guaranteed to "fit" in that same array; this makes it possible for code to sort or permute the elements in an array of arbitrary reference type without having to know the type of the array in question.